# Gnuplot fill error bars as transparent shades

Tags: 2d, gnuplot, transparency, errorbar

[image]

Hi all,

I have input data as:

x(1),y(2),z(2)

x(2),y(2),z(2)

and so on,

where x and y values are on x-axis and y-axis, respectively, and the z values are the error bars. 
From Gnuplot, how could I reproduce the figure, in which the error bars of multiple plots are transparent?

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The plot style `with filledcurves` can be used with 3 columns of input data to produce the shaded regions. The central lines would have to be drawn separately.
Gnuplot expects input

x y1 y2

so if your data is in the form x, y, delta-y you can construct the gnuplot commands by constructing y1 and y2 in the `using` specifier

```
set term png truecolor  # or "set term pngcairo"
set output 'fill.png'
#
set style fill transparent solid 0.25 # partial transparency
set style fill noborder # no separate top/bottom lines
plot 'data' using 1:2 with lines lc "blue" title "Force", \
     'data' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "blue" notitle, \
     'data' using ($1-Shift):2 with lines lc "green" title "Shift", \
     'data' using ($1-Shift):($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "green" notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ethan. I had tried this your set up before. However, unfortunately it did not work and I do not know why.

Comment: I don't believe that the "problem" be my gnuplot version, since in principle the "transparent solid" syntax is compiling well.

Comment: "did not work" is not a helpful error report.  What didn't work?  No plot? No transparency? No filled area?  What gnuplot version?  What output terminal?

Comment: Filled area, but no transparency. The output is set as "set terminal png size 2000,2000 enhanced font "Times-Roman, 30""
Sorry for not provide these informations before.

Comment: You can either use `set term png truecolor` for the libgd-based png terminal, or `set term pngcairo` for the libcairo-based png terminal.

Comment: Lets try it, sir.